# How to create views in Access 2007?

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Now in SQL views are tables which can be used for data abstraction (showing specific data to required users). 
Also you can edit data and insert data into the original table through views. What I want is an equivalent of this in access.
I have been able to create a view table in access but the problem is that it cannot be used to update the record set.

Answer (score 3):

In Jet databases, the equivalent of a view is a saved query.  You should be able to update the base tables through the query, provided that the query obeys certain rules.  These rules are documented in the [Access 2007 help](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/edit-data-in-a-query-HA010097876.aspx).  If you provide your view definition and some details about the base table(s), we can give some specific advice about why the query isn't updatable.

Comment: You see, I can update my database by a form application or by writing the SQL update query.But then I will have to refer to my original database or a report to look up the data. What I want is to update the data in my database directly, just like a end-user. I do not want my end-user to have any knowledge in SQL. I just want him/her to edit/update the data. But since the user is not administrator so he/she cannot just type in the values in the table.  I need Data Abstraction to be implemented.

Comment: @name_space: you have to build an APPLICATION to allow your users to update the data without writing SQL. Access makes that very easy, as when you create a bound form, it automatically updates the underlying data table.